# Selecting results from 2 tables based on the variables in 3th table

Tags: mysql

I have 2 tabes in my database:

```
users - userID(primary key), username, password
courses - id(primary key), name, text
subscriptions - id(primary key), curso_id, user_id
```

right in the subscription table I am writing the users UserID inside -> user_id with the id of the course for which he is subscribed curso_id so the results in the subscrption database are like

```
subscribtions table: 
id  user_id   curso_id
1      12         1
2      5          1
3      12         2 
4      6          7
```

this is the users table:

```
users table
userID   username password
   1        user1  passw1
   2
   3
   4
```

and this is the courses table:

```
course table:
   id   course_name  descriotion
    1   course one   text
    2
    3
```

My question is how to make a sql Query which first select the course by `$row['id']` which indicates the id variable from the courses database, and after that based on the 3th table subscription to list all the users which are subscribed to this course number. ?

and second question is how to list number of the subscribed users for a course selected by

```
$row['id']
```

Here is some kind of the alghorytm logic that I have right now

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE id=5.courses(select from the database 'courses') AND 5-> SELECT ALL FROM table subscriptions user_id equal to id from table users
```

Comment: Can you tell us what you've tried?

Comment: problem is I am not really sure how to make the relation between the different tabes and then set e rules or selection i guess the option is to JOIN the tables but then how to set the rules of selection

Comment: This is pretty basic stuff. I'd suggest checking out a SQL tutorial. http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

okay I found the way and here is the mysql query:

```
    FROM users
INNER JOIN subscriptions
ON users.userID = subscriptions.user_id
WHERE subscriptions.curso_id = $ids"
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understood what you try to achieve, but if you want a list that shows you every user in every course with the name of the course and ordered by course name, this should make the deal.

```
select t1.*, t2.*, t3.* from users as t1, courses as t2, subscriptions as t3 where t3.user_id = t1.userID and t3.curso_id = t2.id order by t2.id
```

Not the nicest way to do this and from a performance aspect I would recommend to put this in several statements as joins are usually slow.

Comment: I want to list all the users subscribed to selected course, but only one course at a time. the course which is selected is identifyed by $row['id']